# SQL Server 2005 installation from command prompt

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using following command to install SQL Server 2005 manually.

```
H:\SQLServer\SQLExpr.exe /ADDLOCAL="All"/INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS"/SAPWD="test123"
```

It returns no error, but does not acutally install SQL Server too.
First it shows [image]

When I click next, it shows a report 
[image]

and on clicking OK, it closes.  But SQL Server is not installed.
Thanks

Comment: What is the source of installation files? from where you downloaded these files?

Comment: The "report" that you're seeing is a usage screen, suggesting that you didn't specify the parameters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory glance of [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.90).aspx) suggests you need to specify at least one of `/qn` or `/qb` on the command line.

> The `/qn` switch suppresses all Setup dialog boxes and error messages. If the `/qn` switch is specified, all Setup messages, including error messages, are written to Setup log files. For more information about log files, see How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files.
>
> The `/qb` switch allows the display of basic Setup dialog boxes. Error messages are also displayed.

Although I've never had to install SQL Server from the command line before, it seems that simply by reading the documentation it is clear the easiest way to do this is with an options file:

> ## To run a command prompt installation of SQL Server 2005 using an .ini file
>
> Run `Setup.exe` from the command prompt:
>
> ```
> <CD or DVD Drive>\Setup.exe /settings C:/set.ini /qn
> ```

Comment: Yup ! I have already tried qb but it reaches a certain level adn then disappears.  No installation of SQL Server

Comment: Try putting spaces in between your parameters. Note that if an error occurred you should be able to see it in the error logs.